# regarding using an excel file to overwrite a part of another excel file

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have two excel files, one file (a2) has a overlap with another file (a1) in terms of a given column, like ID. I want to use the information included in a2 to overwrite the ones included in a1. For instance, I want to use the grade in a2 to overwrite the corresponding grade in a1 with the same ID. How to do that in Excel?

Here is an example of a1

[image]

Here is an example of a2

[image]

Comment: Take a close look at the VLOOKUP function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basic logic for this would be something like:

- On a1.xlsx - check if id exists on a2.xlsx
- If it does, use the associated grade value on a2.xlsx
- If it doesnt, use the current value in a1.xlsx

workbook setup https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpudvzbx6qnuvck/Screenshot%202014-08-11%2012.33.52.png

Create a combined grade field on a1.xlsx, since i couldnt think of a way to store both the grade on a1.xlsx and overwrite it at the same time, and use the following formula on cell C2 then drag down

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,[a2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$3,1,FALSE)),B2,VLOOKUP(A2,[a2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$B$3,2,FALSE))
```

a1.xlsx modified https://www.dropbox.com/s/1og79gqcm8e9v8l/Screenshot%202014-08-11%2012.29.30.png

if you want to overwrite the current grade column, just copy the fields in combined grade. goto edit > paste special > select "Values" from Paste > Click "OK"

Hope this helps!